# How to use 2 datasources with Ebean on a Play Framework 2.5 project?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.5

I would like to split my default datasource to 2 different datasources (2 databases). I set my application.conf file:

```
db {

  common.driver = org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  common.username = "root"
  common.password = "123456"
  common.url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost/common"

  laundry.driver = org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  laundry.username = "root"
  laundry.password = "123456"
  laundry.url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost/laundry"

  #default.logSql=true
}
```

and I set the ebean models:

```
ebean.common = ["models.Unit", "models.Building", "models.User"]
ebean.laundry = ["models.Machine", "models.Schedule", "models.Event"]
```

but I get a fatal error at compile time:

```
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class models.Unit is not enhanced?
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:32)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:21):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class models.Unit is not enhanced?
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setEntityBeanClass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1414)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createByteCode(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1286)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1208)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:711)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:326)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:141)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:140)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:45)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:108)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:67)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$start$3(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1288)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.start(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:38)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions$$FastClassByGuice$$52c94231.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:168)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

2) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class models.Unit is not enhanced?
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:32)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:21):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:22):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class models.Unit is not enhanced?
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setEntityBeanClass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1414)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createByteCode(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1286)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1208)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:711)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:326)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:141)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:140)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:45)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:108)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:67)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$start$3(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1288)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.start(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:38)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions$$FastClassByGuice$$52c94231.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:168)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

2 errors
```

My Unit.java file looks like:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "units")
public class Unit extends Entity
{
    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private User owner;

    @Required
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private static Finder<Long,Unit> find = new Finder<Long,Unit>(Unit.class);

    public User getOwner()
    {
        return owner;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLabel()
    {
        return getName();
    }

    public void setOwner(Long id)
    {
        owner = User.getById(id);
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete()
    {
        for (User user : User.findByUnit(this))
        {
            user.updateUnit(null);
        }

        return super.delete();
    }

    public static Unit getById(Long id)
    {
        return find.byId(id);
    }

    public static List<Unit> findAll()
    {
        return find.all();
    }
}
```

And Entity.java is like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity extends Model
{
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLabel()
    {
        return "";
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt()
    {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isPersistent()
    {
        return id > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void save()
    {
        createdAt();
        super.save();
    }

    public void update()
    {
        updatedAt();
        super.update();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) return false;
        if (!(entity instanceof Entity)) return false;
        return id == ((Entity) entity).id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return (int) id;
    }

    private void createdAt()
    {
        createdAt = updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    private void updatedAt()
    {
        updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

Should I list all the classes in `ebean.XXX = []`? Why do I get this error even with the right list?

Comment: Suggestion: ebean.<NAME> = ["models.*"]